# data-attribute in form tag

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I just stumbled upon a weird problem today, and asked myself if someone knew, what causes this?

If I try to submit a form via jQuery and try to get a custom data-attribute, it will be "undefined".
Here is the code to show you

HTML

```
<form action="/" method="POST" data-test="passed">
    <input type="text" name="in1" value="valuable" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){

       // this will work
       alert(this.action);

       // this will fail
       alert(this.data-test);

       return false;
   });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7etzas0m/

I hope someone is interested, and can answer my question.
Thanks

Comment: `this.dataset.test` - using the [data-api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset) - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7etzas0m/4/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why is it, that I have to treat data-attributes differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to get data attributes. Try this:

```
alert($(this).data('test'));
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/7etzas0m/2/)**

Answer (score 3):

You can read attributes using:

jQuery [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/):

```
alert($(this).attr('data-test'));
```

jQuery [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
alert($(this).data('test'));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Continuing** your non-jQuery approach . just use :

```
if (this.dataset) 
{
 alert(this.dataset["test"]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7etzas0m/3/

Comment: probably should warn about older browser support

Comment: @FabianMaurer indeed. I just wanted you to know that it is accessible also in the vanila way. but you should use jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the info, always appreciate. But its also that im just to used to jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Modify your script to:

```
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){


       alert($(this).attr('action'));


       alert($(this).data('test'));

       return false;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try your **[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7etzas0m/5/) :**

```
    $(function(){
         $('form').submit(function(){        

          alert(this.action);        

          alert($(this).attr('data-test'));

         return false;
      });
   });
```